# Strict comparison of an @ElementCollection of enums in db and a Set of enums using QueryDSL

Tags: querydsl

I have a `FamilyAdvertisement` JPA entity that has a collection/set of `ChildcareType`'s enums as follows:

```
@ElementCollection
private Set<ChildcareType> childcareTypes;
```

Here is the enum:

```
public enum ChildcareType {
    SINGLE, SHARED, OUT_OF_SCHOOL, BABY_SITTING;
}
```

**I want, given a collection/set of required ChildcareTypes passed as a parameter to match only those familyAdvertisements that have the same set of ChildcareTypes.**

Let's take an example: say only three instances of `FamilyAdvertisement` have the following set of `SINGLE` and `SHARED`. I want only those three instances to be returned by my QueryDSL query.

An instance with `SINGLE` only will not be returned.

Another instance with `SINGLE`, `SHARED` and `BABY_SITTING` will not be returned.

I have not been able to find the relevant operator to compare the passed in parameter (`Set<ChildcareType> requiredChildcareTypes`) and the following `SetPath`: `QFamilyAdvertisement.familyAdvertisement.childcareTypes`

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One high level way to express it is like this

```
query.from(familyAdvertisement)
     .where(
         familyAdvertisement.childcareTypes.contains(SINGLE),
         familyAdvertisement.childcareTypes.contains(SHARED),
         familyAdvertisement.childcareTypes.size().eq(2))
     .list(familyAdvertisement);
```

You will need to populate the where part dynamically.

If you want more control of the resulting SQL use left joins or exist clauses for the `contains` rows and a not exists for `size eq` row.

CollectionExpressions do not provide the `eq`method, since most backends don't support it.